# Inline кнопка в aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

В программировании полный 0, пишу магазин для себя на Python с помощью aiogram. Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать вывод такой менюшки, над полем ввода текста,с картинкой и описанием после нажатия на Inline кнопку?
[image: Пример]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: https://core.telegram.org/bots/inline и https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inline-mode, у aiogram всё есть для работы с InlineQuery

Comment: Писать полный код я не буду, но скину документацию. Там много полезной информации - https://mastergroosha.github.io/telegram-tutorial-2/inline_mode/